# Getting Include parameters to work in Octopress/Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, octopress

I'm using Octopress 2.0 and can't seem to get parameters to work when I set an include.

I'm basically trying to do:

{% include foo.html bar="Hello World" %}

When I load the page I get this error: Include file ‘foo.html bar="Hello World"' contains invalid characters or sequences

According to Jekyll documentation, this should work, right?

Comment: Some code to show us ?

Answer (score 0):

The include directive is ok and produces no error.

```
{% include foo.html bar="Hello World" %}
```

Look for an error into _includes/foo.html or send code for further investigation.